# Does anyone JD K 7 for Mac is a direct download link

Tags: java-7

Does anyone JD K 7 for Mac is a direct download link
oracle website dont open for me
please sen for me a direct link of java development kit(jdk) 7 for mac ocx
thank

Answer (score 0):

The best place you can download Java is from Oracle.

Current Link to Java 7 for mac is http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

When attempting to download from this link kindly ensure that you **accept the license agreement**, since the radio button would be set to "Decline license agreement".

Without accepting the license agreement you will not be able to download the JDK.